# Get JSON value from array in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON

```
      [
           {
          "part_number": {
             "id": "1",
             "text": "962-00031-17A004"
          },
          "categoria": null,
          "codigo_cti": "",
          "fabricante": null,
          "modelo": null,
          "numero_serie": "",
          "obs": ""
       }
    ]
```

And I use the code bellow to collect data from it. If I select to extract obs, it works fine. I would like to know how can I collect the text and ID from part_number.

```
$produtos = json_decode($_POST['produtos'], true);  

foreach($produtos as $produto){
    echo $produto["obs"]; //WORKS FINE
    echo $produto["part_number"]["text"]; //DOES NOT WORK
}
```

Comment: Try dumping the `$produto` variable using `var_dump($produto)` to see all the values in the array.

Comment: part_number is not the key, it's inside another object without a key

Comment: WFM https://3v4l.org/L7juj

Comment: I see its working. Try using `echo '<pre>';print_r($produtos);`

Comment: For me its working. echo $produto["part_number"]["text"]; .

Comment: The things is `echo $produto["part_number"]["text"];` is actually working. The previous line is an empty string which is why it doesn't print anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn it into an object and not array first - its easier and Object Orientated is the way to go.

Here is a working example;

```
$json = '[
       {

      "part_number": {

         "id": "1",

         "text": "962-00031-17A004"

      },

      "categoria": null,

      "codigo_cti": "",

      "fabricante": null,

      "modelo": null,

      "numero_serie": "",

      "obs": ""

   }

]';

$produtos = json_decode($json, false);  


foreach($produtos as $produto){
   echo $produto->part_number->id;
}
```

Comment: How does this help? The only difference is that objects aren't converted. If it's not working with arrays, there's probably the same issue with using them as objects.

Comment: @JonStirling Objects are much easier to deal with then arrays when converting JSON

Comment: @JamieSterling Thanks for the example

Comment: @CiaranSynnott, thanks for your answer. It worked fine!

Comment: @CiaranSynnott That's not the point. Imo, the example doesn't really change anything other than how you access stuff.